# Make animation slower (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to make animation of the block by changing its `position`.

Like, move the block from the left to the middle by animation of the css `left`.

The problem is, animation process happens with the same speed from the beginning to the end.

I want to make animation slower at the end, it should slow down when it comes to the finish point.

How can I do this? I've read about easing plugin, but don't know which effect should I use, which is the wanted one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want an ease-out effect. Here are some demos:

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc6/demos/effects_easings/default.html

EDIT:

Here's a more "official" demo page:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html

Comment: Nice find for the jquery easing demo page.

Answer (score 3):

This is an awesome reference for have the easing effects behave: http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/misc/transitions.html. Yes I know this is for the actionscript library `Tweener` but all of the easing names are the same(For the most part).

You're looking for `easeOut` or `easeOutQuad` or `easeOutCubic`. (They are in order of how quickly they will start slowing down)

Answer (score 1):

Try somthing like this:

```
$('#yourBlock').animate({
    left: newValue
}, 500, 'easeOut')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imgAnimate").click(function () {
        $("#imgAnimate").animate({ "opacity": 0.0, left: '800px' }, 2500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could use some explanation.